# How to make visual studio solution file from .proj files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, solution

I have a msbuild project file myproject.proj. Now is there any way I can make a solution file (`.sln`) from the `.proj` file. If this is not possible. Is there any ways I can make a solution file from a group of `csproj` files?

Comment: are you asking automation? or manual way?

Comment: please explain both ways. I will select the better one :)

Comment: A solution file contains just references to projects (like csproj, vcproj, etc). If you already have a project then just open it in studio - you will be prompted to create new solution (which will include you project).

Comment: @ѕтƒ did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do manually.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. File>Open>Project/Solution
3. Provide/Select existing vcxproj file.
4. File>Save Solution. Provide name. Or If you fire build, it will ask you for name first time.

Same can be done for many vcxproj as well. Repeat step 3.